# Kerberos Authentication in True Client LR

Tags: vugen, loadrunner

How to implement Kerberos Authentication in True Client LR?

We are trying to record one application in true client protocol which is using kerbros authentication.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to record Kerberos authentication using TruClient Web protocol and Chromium browser.
Please select the “Prompt me for NTLM credentials in Chromium” in TruClient General Settings under “Browser Settings” tab.
Make sure to select “Chromium” as the development browser.
Upon recording, you will be prompt for credentials and your input will be recorded.
Later on, the recorded step can be enhanced and parametrize as describe in the above blog post.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, implementing authentication in TruClient is quite straightforward.

See this blog post on the subject:

https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/How-to-record-and-enhance-the-browser-s-native-login-prompt-in/ba-p/1618668

Note that the actual implementation depends on your application and environment.

Comment: Hi Edo,

Thanks for your response.

I have tried these steps but it did not work for my application. The application is Using Kerberos Authentication, So are these steps also valid for kerberos authentication?